# Function in R to get the SE of values for several dates, with each dates values being the sum of previous dates values and SE taken each time

Tags: r, function, math, dplyr, statistics

My data:

| treatment | replicate | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| city | 1 | May13 | 1 |
| city | 2 | May13 | 3 |
| rural | 1 | May13 | 11 |
| rural | 2 | May13 | 7 |
| city | 1 | May20 | 2 |
| city | 2 | May20 | 0 |
| rural | 1 | May20 | 19 |
| rural | 2 | May20 | 12 |
| city | 1 | May27 | 5 |
| city | 2 | May27 | 0 |
| rural | 1 | May27 | 21 |
| rural | 2 | May27 | 14 |

I already have a function that sums the values for each date across replicates, then takes the mean, and for each additional date takes the cumulative sum of that date plus the previous, and divides by the number of replicates, and so on:

```
data %>% group_by(treatment, date) %>% summarize(value = mean(value)) %>% mutate(value = cumsum(value))
```

What I would like to do now is obtain standard error for each date, with each date's values being itself plus the values of the all prior dates, which for the above dataset would give this result:

| treatment | date | mean | SE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| city | May13 | 2 | 1 |
| rural | May13 | 9 | 2 |
| city | May20 | 3 | 0 |
| rural | May20 | 24.5 | 5.5 |
| city | May27 | 5.5 | 2.5 |
| rural | May27 | 42 | 9 |

So far, I can only come up with code to get the standard error for each date, but independent of the other dates. Or, I can code to get standard error for each date, independent of other dates, but then cumulatively summed, which is also not what I want:

```
data %>% group_by(treatment, date) %>% 
  summarize(value = mean(value)) %>% mutate(value = cumsum(value), std.error(value))

se <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

b<-transform(aggregate(value~treatment+date,data,cumsum),
             value= ave(value, treatment, FUN=cumsum))
```

I am trying to get the SE for date 1. Then, I want to add the values of dates 1 and 2 together (within replicate) then take the SE for that vector. For date 3, I want to add the values of the previous 2 dates to date 3 and then take the SE. Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you provide a detailed numerical example, for instance what is the computation that gives SE=0 for city/May20?

Comment: Can you clarify: in your desired output you show one SE per date-treatment combo, but in the text you say you want to keep the replicates separate - what is your desired output?

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. For the May 20th date, the computation is as follows: May13, city, rep1 = 1; May13, city, rep2 = 3; city ; May20, city, rep1 = 2; May20, city, rep2 = 0. Therefore, May20, city, rep1 cumulative is 3 (1+2), and May20 city, rep2 cumulative is 3 (3+0).  Using s = sqrt((sum(x-xbar)^2)/(N-1)) = sqrt(0) = 0

Answer (score 1):

I like dplyr as much as the next person but sometimes a simple loop can make the code and logic much more readable and understandable imo:

```
 getSE <- function(data.in){
  
  unique.dates <- unique(data.in$date)
  
  n.dates <- length(unique.dates)
  n.treatments <- length(unique(data.in$treatment))
  
  date.list <- list()
  
  for(i in 1:n.dates){
    
    date.list <- append(date.list, unique.dates[[i]])
    
    data.flt <- filter(data.in, date %in% date.list)
    
    temp <- data.flt %>% 
      group_by(treatment, replicate) %>% 
      mutate(rep.sum = sum(value)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      group_by(treatment) %>% 
      summarise(se = se(rep.sum)) %>% 
      mutate(date = unique.dates[[i]])
    
    if(i == 1){
      data.out <- temp
    } else {
      data.out <- bind_rows(data.out, temp)
    }
    
  }
  data.out <- select(data.out, treatment, date, se)
  return(data.out)
}

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  treatment date     se
  <chr>     <chr> <dbl>
1 city      May13  1   
2 rural     May13  2   
3 city      May20  0   
4 rural     May20  3.18
5 city      May27  1.12
6 rural     May27  4.02
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bowhaven for your answer! I am wondering if there is a way to modify the function so that for each date (for example May20), the values for the previous date (May13) are first added, then the SEM is taken. As it is now, each SEM looks like it's being computed for that date alone. Here is an example of what I mean: For city, both reps, values for date1 + values for date2 = 1+2 =3, and 3+0 = 3 respectively. So values for city, May20 would be 3 for both reps, which would give a SE of zero. Date 3 would be the SE of the values of all three dates for both reps, and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I understand now and have changed the code to first sum the values per treatment-rep combo then calculate SE (just three extra lines in the dplyr pipe). I would just point out that summing replicates then calculating SE seems like a statistically unusual thing to do, but that's for another forum ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a bit on how you think about it.  The way you've framed the problem, you're calculating the SE for each date-treatment pair.  If you think about the mean each day as a random variable, that has a normal distribution with a given standard error, then when you sum up the means you should probably calculate the variance of the summed means by summing up the sampling variances.  We know that the variance of a linear combination is:

[image]

Assuming that the covariance between means of different dates is zero, then you could just sum up the squared standard errors and take the square root of the sum to get the sampling variability of the sum.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~treatment,   ~replicate, ~date,  ~value,
"city", 1,  "May13",    1,
"city", 2,  "May13",    3,
"rural",    1,  "May13",    11,
"rural",    2,  "May13",    7,
"city", 1,  "May20",    2,
"city", 2,  "May20",    0,
"rural",    1,  "May20",    19,
"rural",    2,  "May20",    12,
"city", 1,  "May27",    5,
"city", 2,  "May27",    0,
"rural",    1,  "May27",    21,
"rural",    2,  "May27",    14)



dat %>% group_by(treatment, date) %>% 
  summarize(sv = var(value)/n(), 
            value = mean(value)) %>% 
  mutate(value = cumsum(value), 
         se = sqrt(cumsum(sv)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'treatment'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Groups:   treatment [2]
#>   treatment date     sv value    se
#>   <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 city      May13  1      2    1   
#> 2 city      May20  1      3    1.41
#> 3 city      May27  6.25   5.5  2.87
#> 4 rural     May13  4      9    2   
#> 5 rural     May20 12.2   24.5  4.03
#> 6 rural     May27 12.2   42    5.34
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>